# i need check for match in different div's

Tags: javascript

hi this is my first project on javascript, I made a memory game with 3 divs in the same section. first div is 8 cards, second 12 and third is 16. and I made this cardCorrect function to count the correct cards, but I need this for the other divs to with different value's! I am now stuck for a long time on this.

I found nothing on google about this

```js
let easyMode = document.getElementById("easy");
let mediumMode = document.getElementById("medium");
let hardMode = document.getElementById("hard");
let controlS = document.getElementById("control");
let back = document.getElementById("menuButtons");

// functions for gamemode buttons and Quit button
function goBack(){
  resetGame();
  back.style.display = "";
  easyMode.style.display = "none";
  mediumMode.style.display = "none";
  hardMode.style.display = "none";
  controlS.style.display= "none";
}

function gameModeEasy() {
  easyMode.style.display = "";
  controlS.style.display= "";
  back.style.display = "none";
}

function gameModeMedium() {
  mediumMode.style.display = "";
  controlS.style.display= "";
  back.style.display = "none";
}

function gameModeHard() {
  hardMode.style.display = "";
  controlS.style.display= "";
  back.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
let cardCorrect = 0;

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.image === secondCard.dataset.image;

  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  cardCorrect++
  console.log(cardCorrect)
  if (cardCorrect === 4) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Congratulations! You found all the pairs!"); 
  }, 1000)
};
```

Comment: the code checks the cardCorrect after 2 cards match, in my first div i have 8 cards so after 4 cardCorrect i get the alert, but in the other divs i have more cards so it alerts to early, sorry for my bad english, and i am new to javascript

Comment: Your code snippet has JS in the CSS part... I may understand it's not that easy for new SO users... But to that point is quite surprising. Please edit and add the HTML at the right place.

Comment: I see functions, but nothing that produces output (and I don't see output when I run the snippet). Can you post something that shows the behavior you don't like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set "4" as parameter in disableCards.

 Like This,

```
function disableCards(matchCount) {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  cardCorrect++
  console.log(cardCorrect)
  if (cardCorrect === matchCount) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Congratulations! You found all the pairs!"); 
  }, 1000)
};
```

and Call it like this,

```
function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.image === secondCard.dataset.image;
  let matchCount = checkDivAndReturnMatchCount();

  isMatch ? disableCards(matchCount) : unflipCards();
}
```

(In this example, "checkDivAndReturnMatchCount" function is a new function to check what div you clicked and return correct matchCount value for the div.)

Comment: i tried                                                                                                                             
 </br> function checkDivAndReturnMatchCount() {
  if(cards){return 4;  }
  if(cards1){ return 6;}
  if(cards2){ return 8; }
}                                                                                                                                      
   <br> and function checkDivAndReturnMatchCount() {
  if(easyMode){return 4;  }
  if(mediumMode){ return 6;}
  if(hardMode{ return 8; }
} <br>  but it only return 4 it don't check te ohter div

Comment: i tried    function checkDivAndReturnMatchCount() {
  if(cards){return 4;  }
  if(cards1){ return 6;}
  if(cards2){ return 8; }
}   and i tried  function checkDivAndReturnMatchCount() {
  if(easyMode){return 4;  }
  if(mediumMode){ return 6;}
  if(hardMorde){ return 8; }
}    But it only returns 4 and the other 2 are not working?

Comment: I think your function checkDivAndReturnMatchCount() in comment has no way to check what is current mode. You should declare what mode is currently activated. For example, let gameMode = "";  if (easyMode.style.display != 'none') { gameMode = 'easy'; } if (mediumMode.style.display != 'none') { gameMode = 'medium';}

Comment: And use 'gameMode' to set matchCount. Like, if (gameMode == 'easy') { matchCount = 4; } else if (gameMode == 'medium') { matchCount = 8; } ... return matchCount;

Comment: yes thank you siwol27 this fixed my issue

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Have a nice day, Osmanli40!